# What to use for $. when method is given by the value of a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had the need to substitute variables for all parts of a common jquery call.
So given the following code:

```
$('#some_id').html('bar');
```

This works as expected:

```
var selector = '#some_id';
var action = 'html';
var input = 'bar';    
$(selector)[action](input);
```

So now the question becomes, how do I make a call without the selector portion like the following:

```
$.myFunction('foo');
```

This does not work:

```
var action = 'myFunction';
var input = 'foo';
$.[action](input);
```

So what is the right pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without the period and it should work.

```
$[action](input);
```